# TFDSQLiteSecurity doesn't require existing password if already logged in?

Tags: c++builder, firedac

The docs for `TFDSQLiteSecurity` state it needs both the old and new password for `ChangePassword()` but I find if I'm already connected to the database, I can enter any garbage in the `Password` field and it still changes it?

I presume if you want to check the password you have to `TFDConnection::Connected=false` before using the `TFDSQLiteSecurity::ChangePassword()` to check the source password?

Is that by design?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

> I find if I'm already connected to the database, I can enter any garbage in the Password field and it still changes it?

The current password is used only when making a new connection.

> I presume if you want to check the password you have to `TFDConnection::Connected=false` before using the `TFDSQLiteSecurity::ChangePassword()` to check the source password?

That, or you can use [`CheckEncryption()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.SQLite.TFDSQLiteSecurity.CheckEncryption) instead.